# Android Studio v23 app bar failer, Why?

Tags: android

I don't know why or what happen, why my next menu item is below the setting but the tutorial is beside the setting.

So far I only know the different is v21 and v23.

I searched for days, but no solution or relevant found.

Here is my menu code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.vsh.jiin.cloudsys.JobMainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigate"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

[image: Screenshot]

after suggestion of "ifRoom" here it go..... T_T

[ifRoom Mode - Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq9an.png)

Comment: you want side by side menu icons in action bar? can change the  android:showAsAction="ifroom". Try this once

Comment: Change `android:showAsAction` to `app:showAsAction`.

Comment: OMG! you are right Andrew T!, just a little tiny different of android vs app and it solve, honestly i didnt awake of this due to i coding with #auto complete of coding typing. Once again, thanks